# How to zip 2 different length array so that can loop in django loop?

Tags: python, arrays, django, html

I have 2 arrays:

First array:

**['Tan','Goh','Tio']**

Second array:

**[['Honda','Toyota','Proton'],['Toyota'],['Proton','Lambo']]**

How to zip this 2 arrays so that when i apply this code:

```
{% for i in loop_times %}

     {{i|safe}}

{% endfor %}
```

So,the out put will be like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">
    <span class="ca-icon">Tan</span>
    <div class="ca-content">
        <h3 class="ca-main">Honda</h2>
        <h3 class="ca-sub">Toyota</h3>
        <h3 class="ca-sub">Proton</h3>
    </div>
    </a>
</li>

<li>
    <a href="#">
    <span class="ca-icon">Goh</span>
    <div class="ca-content">
        <h3 class="ca-sub">Toyota</h3>
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
    <span class="ca-icon">Tio</span>
    <div class="ca-content">
        <h3 class="ca-main">Proton</h2>
        <h3 class="ca-sub">Lambo</h3>
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Anyone can share me idea? I have study this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/ but I still not able to understand, can anyone give some ideas ?

Comment: doesn't `list(zip(['Tan','Goh','Tio'], [['Honda','Toyota','Proton'],['Toyota'],['Proton','Lambo']]))` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in views.

```
l = ['Tan', 'Goh', 'Tio']
d = [['Honda', 'Toyota', 'Proton'], ['Toyota'], ['Proton', 'Lambo']]
list = dict(zip(l, d))
```

in the template:

```
{% for key, values in list.items %}
    <a href="#">
    <span class="ca-icon">{{ key }}</span>
    <div class="ca-content">
        {% for v in values %}
        <h3 class="ca-main">{{ v }}</h2>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```